# Welldefined Hilbert-Schmidt Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

How can I show that the general Hilbert-Schmidt-Operators as a linear map defined for $p$ and $q$ with the condition as always by

$Tf(x) := \int_Y k(x,y)f(y)d\nu (y)$

with $k(x,y)$ $\mu$x$\nu$-measurable is welldefined for $f\in L^p (\nu)$?
I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with $L^p$ ? [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) are in Hilbert spaces, right ?

Comment: oh sorry, that was a bit lazy...  We have two $\sigma$ finite measure spaces $(X,\mathbb{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathbb{B},\nu)$ and $L^p(\nu)$ is the Lebesgue space.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Explain clearly what you know and what you want to show (and your operator isn't a [Hilbert-Schmidt operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator))

Comment: okay, but for $p=q=2$ we have a HS-Operator?!

Comment: I want to you that the linear map $T$ is welldefinied for $f\in L^p (\nu)$ and $T: L^p (\nu) \rightarrow L^p (\mu)$

Comment: is that more clear?

Comment: You cannot show what you want. You need some assumptions on $k $ in addition to measurability.

Comment: another thing I missed, sorry: $[\int_X ( \int_Y \vert k(x,y)\vert ^q d\nu(y))^{p/q}d\mu (x)]^{1/p} < \infty$

Comment: anyone out there with any suggestions :(?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply Holder's Inequality and Fubini-Tonelli to the product $k(x,\cdot)f$.